# Ubuntu Custom ls Listings With Strings

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying to add certain strings to file types in the bash "ls" command.

For example, "ls"-ing a directory with an .exe inside, would appear as

```
<file name>*
```

E.g.

```
helloworld*
```

Instead of

```
helloworld
```

**Note: the * appended.**

**How might I acheive this?** I don't have any experience with bash so I don't know what to Google, but bless my socks I did try for a good hour.

I have already customized the bash colours using this: http://hocuspokus.net/2008/01/a-better-ls-for-mac-os-x/

So if it ties in, that's great.

Comment: ``ls -F`` appends ``*`` for executables  and ``/``  for directories

Comment: @sotapme I want this permanently, as I will use it for other file types.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` represent an executable, this can be achieved with `-F` option to the ls.

The first place to look for anything in *nix is the `man` page for that command. Try to make a habbit of reading `man` pages, they have a lot of info.

Do a `man ls` to get all info about the command-switches, options and output of this command.

Some references-

- [Linux man page for ls](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls)
- You can also check some useful examples at the [geekStuff link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/linux-ls-command-examples/).

---

#### Edit

You can also create an alias if you need that behaviour always. Example in bash shell you can do

```
 alias ls='ls -F --color=auto'
```

Comment: I want this as permanent setting I can alter, and call with simply `ls` as I will be using it for other file types. I will read man now though.

Comment: @tsujp, add the alias to your ~/.bashrc file